# At least one contact should have checbox checked Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning

i have the below scenario. One account is having many contacts. **contact_status__c** is a checkbox field on contact. i am trying to write a trigger which will check at least 1 contact should have this checkbox checked. if that account has one contact and if user makes the field uncheck, it should throw an error

Below code is not working.

> 'You are trying to remove last contact status checkbox which is not
>   allowed'

trigger -

```
trigger checkaccount on contact(before insert, before update){

    List<Id> accID = new List<Id>();
    for(contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.accountId != null){
            accID.add(c.accountId);
        }
    }

    List<account> acc = [select id, (select id, contact_status__c from contacts where contact_status__c = true) from Account WHERE Id In: accID];
    system.debug('@@@@acc ' + acc);
    system.debug('@@@@acc ' + acc[0].contacts);
    Map<id, boolean> bool = new map<id,boolean>();
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(acc.size() == 0 ) {
            c.addError('You are trying to remove last contact status checkbox which is not allowed');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a lot of problems with this code, mostly due to a lack of bulkification (meaning, the code should work right with multiple contacts). You need to use after-insert/after-update instead of before-insert/before-update, otherwise your query won't return the correct values. Further, you need to determine which account matches the contact. Here's a more approximate version you're looking for:

```
trigger checkaccount on contact (after insert, after update) {
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
  }
  accountIds.retainAll(new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT AccountId Id
    FROM Contact
    WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND contact_status__c = true
    GROUP BY AccountId
  ]).keySet());
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.AccountId != null && !accountIds.contains(record.AccountId)) {
      record.addError('You are trying to remove last contact status checkbox which is not allowed');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen `retainAll` nor `Map<Id, AggregateResult>.keySet()` used this way. Great use of both and I learned something new today :-)

Comment: @BrianMiller Glad I could show you something new  There's a lot of cool ways you can mix these methods if you get a bit imaginative.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic simply doesn't do what you're aiming to do.

```
List<account> acc = [select id, (select id, contact_status__c from contacts where contact_status__c = true) from Account WHERE Id In: accID];
```

Here, you query the Accounts of all Contacts in the trigger set.

```
for(Contact c : trigger.new){
    if(acc.size() == 0 ) {
        c.addError('You are trying to remove last contact status checkbox which is not allowed');
    }
```

But here, you're just asking, with `acc.size()`, "Do any of the Contacts in my trigger set have an Account?"

That's not what you want. You seem to want to ask "Does the Account of *this* Contact have any *remaining* Contacts, other than this one, that have `contact_status__c` set to `true`?"

To do that effectively, you'll need to make some changes. First, you'll want to put your Accounts in a Map, so that you can access them via the Contact's `AccountId` field. Here you'll want to use the fact that a `Map<Id, sObject>` has a constructor to which you can directly pass a `List<sObject>`: `Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([QUERY HERE])`.

Then, for each Contact, you'll want to access its related Account's list of Contacts, with `accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Contacts`. But remember to write logic first to check if the Contact has an Account, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

That gets you part of the way there, but there's some additional issues you'll want to consider. Most importantly, your trigger should only react to changes to the `Contact_Status__c` field by adding this error - not to unrelated changes to the Contact. So before you check anything for each Contact, you'll want to check if that field has in fact changed from `true` to `false`, by looking at `Trigger.oldMap`.

Then there's one more consideration. You're running this trigger `before insert`, which doesn't really make sense since you cannot change the field from one value to another during an insert event, and `before update`. In `before update` context, your query will return the *current* value of that field *for records in the trigger set*. You probably want to run this trigger `after update` so that your query results reflect the change being made, and you get back an accurate count of Contacts with the field set.

Answer (score 0):

To do this using `before update` is not correct as result of `soql` will be before the updation and it will show `error(You Error)` even if you are making first contact field `contact_status__c` to `true`.

Clearly as mentioned above, you are getting account size with `acc.size()` which is wrong. Instead of this you can use `acc.contacts.size()` but again for that you have to use loop inside loop.

BTW I've made some modification in your code as below:

```
trigger checkaccount on contact(after insert, after update){
    Set<Id> accID = new Set<Id>();
    for(contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.accountId != null){
            accID.add(c.accountId);
        }
    }

    List<Contact> con= [select id, contact_status__c from contact where contact_status__c = true AND AccountId In: accID];
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(con.size() == 0 ) {
            c.addError('You are trying to remove last contact status checkbox which is not allowed');
        }
    }
}
```

You can further optimize this code by adding `trigger.old` and `trigger.new` comparison to confirm that particular field is changed not some other fields